# Can't require one module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, import

I have some trouble for using react-native-paypal.

```
let PayPal = require('react-native-paypal');
```

I have this error: `Requested keys of a value that is not an object`.
I also try `let PayPal = require('../node_modules/react-native-paypal');` but it didn't work too. I don't know what to do.

Solution: I use paypal-react-native-wrapper  but now I have undefiend is not an object when I initialize the paiement. The error is at the first point .

```
    PayPal.initialize(PayPal.SANDBOX, "AbyfNDFV53djg6w4yYgiug_JaDfBSUiYI7o6NM9HE1CQ_qk9XxbUX0nwcPXXQHaNAWYtDfphQtWB3q4R");
PayPal.pay({
  price: '40.70',
  currency: 'MYR',
  description: 'Your description goes here',
}).then(confirm => console.log(confirm))
  .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Thank for your answer.

Comment: Have you tried importing e.g. `import PayPal from 'react-native-paypal'`?

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
import PayPal from 'react-native-paypal';
```

If this doesn't work, try installing 'react-native-paypal-wrapper' and then do

```
import PayPal from 'react-native-paypal-wrapper';
```

Comment: I try the first one and it doesn't work. I can't install the seconde, react native is not recognize as a internal command.

Comment: can you quickly do `npm list` and share the list with me?

Comment: I have too much missing file for copy them.

Comment: I can import react-native-paypal-wrapper but the code bug. See my first psot.